# Procedural noise displacement changes place if I deform the mesh

Tags: animation, modifiers, displacement, procedural

I was trying to make a "dancing churro" in blender 2.81a.

After modelling churro shape I added some detail with the following simple node tree:

[image]

For "dance" animation I used the wave modifier:

[image]

When I rendered the animation, I noticed that displacement doesn't follow my churro, but stays in place. It's highly visible inside this red circle:

[image]

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

(This is very simple (my first ever) blender project, so the solution is probably simple as well, however, I couldn't find it.
I'd really appreciate help.)

Comment: The displacement works for animations, but you have to learn how to use texture coordinates. If the shape is changing you need to use UV coordinates.

Comment: Watch Bartek Skorupa’s video on how to [Manipulate texture coordinates](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=264)

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. I guess watching a couple of videos on YT is not enough to master blender  and I still have a lot to learn.

By the way, nice coincidence. Bartek Skorupa’s home town Warsaw is also my home town.